# Count vowels and print duplicate vowels

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code that counts the number of vowels from the user input and prints them. Furthermore, what I also want to do is to print out the duplicate vowels.

The first part of the code runs fine and it does print out the number of vowels in whatever the user gives input but the second part does not seem to work. I am attaching the code I have come up with.

```
user_name = input('Please enter your name: ')

count = 0

for vowels in user_name:

    if vowels.lower() == "a" or vowels.lower() == "e" or vowels.lower() == "i" or vowels.lower() == "o" \
            or vowels.lower() == "u":

        count = count + 1

print(f'Number of vowels are {count}')

dupes = ""

for rep_vows in user_name:

    if rep_vows not in dupes:
       # dupes.append(rep_vows)
        print(dupes)
```

Comment: What is wrong weith the second part. Please provide some more context/error's your seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the duplicates, you should be checking if a new vowel was already added to the list (or string) of vowels found.

A simple modification will get you this

```
duples = ''
for rep_vows in user_name:
   if rep_vows in duples:
     print(rep_vows)
   if rep_vows.lower() in "aeiou": 
     duples += rep_vows
```

Since you know how to use `in`, you can change the first part to:

```
for vowels in user_name:
    if vowels.lower() in "aeiou":
        count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For counting things Python has `Counter` dict here is some examples:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import re 

>>> # Count vowels
>>> Counter(re.findall('[aieouAEIOU]', 'Daniel Hilst'))
Counter({'i': 2, 'a': 1, 'e': 1})
>>> # Summing up
>>> sum(Counter(re.findall('[aieouAEIOU]', 'Daniel Hilst')).values())
4

>>> # Count words
>>> Counter(re.findall(r'\w+', 'some text'))
Counter({'some': 1, 'text': 1})
>>>
```

You can find the documentation at collections package docs: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html

Answer (score 0):

I think a native Python Counter is really what you should try to use here. It is just a glorified dictionary but it really trims down the amount of code you need to write to achieve your goal.

```py
from collections import Counter #import Counter from Python's collections standard library

user_name = input('Please enter your name: ')

vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'] # create a list of your vowels

counter = Counter() # initialize counter

for letter in user_name:
    if letter in vowels:
        print(letter)
        counter[letter]+=1

print(counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is ok, but dupes should be a list (of repeated vowels), and you can use another list for the already seen vowels; so when you see a vowel, you check if that one is already in "seen". If the vowel is in seen, you append it to dupes, otherwise, you append it to seen, so when that one repeats, it will be appended to dupes.

And finally, you print the list of dupes.

```
user_name = input('Please enter your name: ')

count = 0

for vowels in user_name:

    if vowels.lower() == "a" or vowels.lower() == "e" or vowels.lower() == "i" or vowels.lower() == "o" or vowels.lower() == "u":

        count = count + 1

print(f'Number of vowels are {count}')

seen = []
dupes = []

for rep_vows in user_name:

    if rep_vows not in seen:
        seen.append(rep_vows)
    else:
        dupes.append(rep_vows)

print(dupes)
```